# libgdx changing sprite color while hurt

Tags: java, colors, libgdx, sprite, game-engine

I am using libgdx to make a little platformer and I would like to make the enemies blink in red while the player hurt them with his weapon.

I already tried to change the sprite color and the sprite batch color with no success, it only melt the new color with the one of the texture.

```
sprite.setColor(Color.RED);
spriteBatch.draw(sprite);
```

the effect I want to achieve is:

[image]

going from sprite texture to full red and then back again.
I think there is something to do with the Blending function, but I am not sure about that. I want to avoid making some red sprite for each monsters of my game.
Does someone know how to achieve this effect?

Comment: Do you set the colours of the bat manually into variables e.g. batBlack, batGrey, batRed? If so, change those values to represent the effect you want.

Comment: The image is a simple png sprite with fixed colors, what I want to do is not modifying the source or the color pixel by pixel. I think I need a mask or something like that

Comment: With a shader - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mIdNru2VO0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a shader like this to change the color of all pixels instead of multiplying them by that color. Use this shader with SpriteBatch by calling `spriteBatch.setShader(shader);`.

This is basically the default SpriteBatch shader, except the final color replaces all non-alpha pixels.

To use this method, you must batch your colored sprites separately from your normal sprites. Call `spriteBatch.setShader(null);` to go back to drawing regular sprites.

```
String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
            + "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
            + "attribute vec2 " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
            + "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" //
            + "varying vec4 v_color;\n" //
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
            + "\n" //
            + "void main()\n" //
            + "{\n" //
            + "   v_color = " + ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
            + "   v_texCoords = " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
            + "   gl_Position =  u_projTrans * " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
            + "}\n";
        String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" //
            + "#define LOWP lowp\n" //
            + "precision mediump float;\n" //
            + "#else\n" //
            + "#define LOWP \n" //
            + "#endif\n" //
            + "varying LOWP vec4 v_color;\n" //
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" //
            + "void main()\n"//
            + "{\n" //
            + "  gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).a;\n" //
            + "}";

        ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it work. At first I wanted to avoid using shaders for this purpose, but it seems this is the good way to go. But what if I want to apply multiples shader programs? Will I'll be forced to user FBO?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. What I would do is, for each layer in your game, sort your sprites that are going to be red this frame into a separate list. First draw all your regular sprites, then change the shader to the custom shader and draw the red sprites, and then change the shader back to null (which switches it back to default).

Comment: Hey@Tenfour04, thanks for your answer, it helped me. Is there a way to set a chosen color programmaticaly to this shader, using the parameter c_color? Hot to do that in the code?

Comment: @Don I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You want to set a color to be used by all the sprites without having to change their vertex colors? I think I misunderstand you because that sounds like just a different way of doing the same thing we're doing here.

Comment: Anyway, you can put a constant color in your shader like this: `const vec4 c_color = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I was wondering if we could use a dynamic approach and set programmaticaly the value of c_color, instead of having a static one in the shader. Maybe using something like myShader.setUniformf("c_color", <custom color>); or something?

Comment: My solution above is dynamic, because it uses the vertex colors of each sprite to color each sprite differently if you like. SpriteBatch in libgdx assigns its current color to every sprite that's submitted to it for drawing, and you can change the color multiple times before the batch is flushed to the GPU. The solution you're suggesting is also dynamic, but it has the drawback that the batch must be flushed every time you change the color (more draw calls).

Comment: But yes, you could do what you're suggesting. Put `uniform vec4 u_color` in either part of the shader, and call `myShader.setUniformf("u_color", color);` or `myShader.setUniformf("u_color", r, g, b, a);` right before `batch.end()`.