# How to color TextureRegion pixel by pixel in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a HashMap of TextureRegions in LibGDX I'm gathering from a single sprite sheet, and am looking to color them differently based on certain conditions. What is the easiest way to color the TextureRegion by pixels (or another way) without tinting it?

I've tried tinting the TextureRegion with setColor(Color tint), but this gives mixed results based on the color. For example, if I have a dark blue and want to color it bright yellow, it turns out an dark orange color instead. I need a definitive way to set the color of each pixel in a TextureRegion with a Hex value.

Thanks guys!

Comment: How are you using the texture regions? In Sprites? It is likely easier to just set the color on the Sprites to tint them. Changing the actual Texture that backs the TextureRegion involves Pixmaps and can be a significant performance hit.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm using a SpriteBatch to draw the TextureRegions. I'm looking into using shaders now, but if there's a better suggestion I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Your options depend on what you're going after. If it's fairly simple, you could just use gray-scale sprites and tint them by setting colors on the Sprites. But if you need multiple hues on the same sprite, you probably will need to modify the pixmap, which is kind of slow. 
If you want multiple hues on the sprite, but only one of them changes, you could do this with multi-texturing and a specialized shader.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this function by using a custom shader. Thanks to @Tenfour04 for providing the shader in a previous answer here:

[libgdx changing sprite color while hurt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099103/libgdx-changing-sprite-color-while-hurt)